# What is Pattern to use Typescript with JSON?

Tags: json, typescript, design-patterns

In TypeScript app, we may have to process data in JSON form. Let's say we have following data structure.

```js
{ "x": 5, "y": 20 }
```

We want to have `distanceFromOrigin` function on above data. I think we can do it in two approach.

#### Approach 1

```js
class Point {
    x: number = 0;
    y: number = 0;

    constructor(init?: Partial<Point>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }

    distanceFromOrigin() {
        return Math.hypot(this.x, this.y);
    }
}

const jsonFromReqest1 = { "x": 5, "y": 20 };
const point = new Point(jsonFromReqest1);

console.log(point.distanceFromOrigin())
```

Above implementation looks nice.
Downsides are:

1. Needs constructor, which takes JSON and creates object. This will become complex when object has nested object and array.
2. Every place we retrieve JSON object we need to make sure we call constructor and convert it into object.

#### Approach 2

```js
interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

const PointService = {
    distanceFromOrigin(point: IPoint) {
        return Math.hypot(point.x, point.y);
    }
}

const jsonFromReqest2 = { "x": 5, "y": 20 };
console.log(PointService.distanceFromOrigin(jsonFromReqest2));
```

Above approach doesn't have downsides of `Approach 1`. But,

1. It doesn't feel object oriented.
2. It is verbose, like we need to write `PointService.distanceFromOrigin`, a very long string.

Are there any other `convenience` and/or `downsides` apart from which I have mentioned, which indicates whether `Approach 1` or `Approach 2` is better.

Comment: Javascript isn't Java, in the second example there's no need to wrap the function in an object, you can just define the function. I think which one you prefer is mostly subjective. All are valid.

Comment: @Evert Yup that's right. I feel `PointService.distanceFromOrigin()` is more readable, I will know `distanceFromOrigin` has something to do with `Point`. Also while writing the code, I have to remember top level entities, like `Point`, and when I write `PointService.` in IDE it give suggestion on all related functions.

Comment: I would say it's more idiomatic to *not* do this and just individually export everything. This also potentially gives you more optimized builds as it makes tree-shaking possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's another approach, which is to use a third-party library to create fully-instantiated objects from your object. For example class-transformer.

https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer